# In Python or Bash, how to convert ASCII back into shift JIS or UTF8?

Tags: python, apache, logging

I need to parse Apache logs on a Japanese server. Since Apache records info in ASCII, the log files contain strings that look like this:

w=%E6%9C%A8%E5%A0%B4

In this case, w is a variable and the string of ASCII was entered by a user in Japanese and converted to ASCII. I would like to translate that string back into Japanese so I can then parse what are the most common variables.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do in either Python or Bash (preferably Python) on how to convert this BACK into Japanese?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`urllib.unquote` the string to convert %-escapes to single characters, then `decode` the string in the proper encoding.

```
import urllib
unicode_string = urllib.unquote(original_string).decode('whatever-encoding')
```

I dunno what that string is encoded in, but [here's a list](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) of the encoding names Python understands.

Comment: it would either be UTF-8 or shift-JIS. I'll try that in a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

[This little pipeline from www.commandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2285/urldecoding)

```
echo w=%E6%9C%A8%E5%A0%B4 | sed -e's/%\([0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\)/\\\\\x\1/g' | xargs echo -e
```

seems to URL decode alright.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I didn't know you could translate locales using sed. Pretty sweet.

Comment: Sure, it's just URL encoded bytes.  Since they are just bytes, it doesn't know anything about encodings, etc.  That would require piping it through `iconv` or something like that.  Or just using the Python solution.